# ПП причинное или сравнительное?

Tags: cинтаксис

*По мере того как шли дни, напряжение возрастало, **ибо чем больше проходило дней без ответа, тем сильнее было его отчаяние**.*

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь четыре предикативных основы: две первые составляют СПП со значением времени, две другие - СПП сопоставительное. А между этими двумя СПП -подчинительные отношения (союз со значением причины ИБО)

Answer (score 3):

Это придаточное сопоставительное со значением постепенного возрастания признака.